# where to place class file common to all apps in a django project?

Tags: django, django-views, project-structure

I am creating a custom decorator class that I will use in each app in my django project.  Where is the best place to put this class file?

I was thinking about creating another app in the project called "Utils" or something.

Is there a standard for this situation?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly where i would put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atma - just make an application using the `manage.py startapp myapp` command.

It seems as if you already know what to do. Not sure why you posted it here.

You can always extend existing classes. It's pretty straightforward.